# How to Make a Specific Folder Visible?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm currently attempting to automate a construction process using the Fusion 360 API, but I'm having trouble understanding the folder system.

Here's where I am so far:

In the first step, based on user input, a different sketch is edited. (This sketch has been extruded, and the bodies are stored in a folder corresponding to the sketch. For example, executing "SketchXYZ" creates bodies stored in the "XYZ" folder.)

However, I'm facing challenges with the next steps:

In the second step, I want to hide everything except for the folder related to the current sketch ("XYZ") and a folder named "Allgemein". Both folders are located within the same component and serve as subfolders of the "Bodies" folder.

In the third step, I plan to save everything visible as an STL file.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to make the hiding part work. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me with this or provide an example.

Comment: Fusion 360 API is not part of APS and it's supported by the team and community on the "Fusion 360 API and Scripts" forum: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fusion-360-api-and-scripts/bd-p/22
Please post your question there